# How Do I pass lists 0f LinkedTreeMap from android to react native frontend?

Tags: android, react-native

I need to pass Lists of LinkedTreeMaps to react native frontend from a @ReactMethod in android

[image: Attached here is the data I need to send]

This is the data I need to send to frontend

Comment: Thanks for your contributions! If you want to learn how to improve your question and answer posts, see [ask] and [answer].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Using WritableArray this can be accomplished.

```
WritableArray data = Arguments.createArray();
List<LinkedTreeMap> accessLogList = (ArrayList) response.get("event_logs");
  for (LinkedTreeMap accessLog : accessLogList) {
       WritableMap accessMap = Arguments.createMap();
       accessMap.putString("dateTime", String.valueOf(accessLog.get("datetime")));
       accessMap.putString("serial", String.valueOf(accessLog.get("device_serial")));
       accessMap.putString("code", getCode(String.valueOf(accessLog.get("code"))));
       data.pushMap(accessMap);
 }
```